# How to solve a definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> If $\int\limits_0^9f(x)\,dx=5$, find $\int\limits_0^3f(3x)\,dx$.

I know how to solve integrals and definite integrals, but I am totally confused on what to do in this problem. I have no idea where to start. Any suggestions would be helpful! Thank you!

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus says that if $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$, then $$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a).$$  Can you use this?

Comment: Let $u=3x$. Using this substitution, the answer should be clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u=3x$, then $du=3dx$ and
$$\int_0^3f(3x)dx=\int_0^9f(u)\frac{du}{3}$$
Thus 
$$\int_0^3f(3x)dx=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^9f(x)dx=\frac{5}{3}$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $t=3x$, then:

$$\int\limits_0^3f(3x)\,dx={1\over 3}\int\limits_0^9f(t)\,dt=...$$

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $t=3x$. Then $\int_{0}^{3}f(3x)dx=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^9f(t)dt=\frac{5}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(3x)$ is a stretch of $f(x)$ by scale factor $1/3$ in the x-direction. So if the integral of $f(x)$ between 0 and k is the sum if the areas of rectangles, then the integral of $f(3x)$ between 0 and $k/3$ is also the sum  of some rectangles - the same height as the ones for $f(x)$, but with each rectangle having $1/3$ the width